# To create a procedure by joining 3 tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to pass devicenumber as a parameter in my proc, I have to select deviceid by device number from devicemaster table, from that deviceid I have to select RegistrationNumber and currentlocation from truck master and distance, frocityid, and tocity from tripdetails (both table deviceid is the common), but fromcityid and tocityid has a cityname which is present in regionmaster table

So by passing DeviceNUmber as a parameter I want a result set having the column RegistrationNumber, currentlocation, distance, fromcityname and tocityname.

I am getting this error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PROC_GMAPSDATA, Line 24
>   Ambiguous column name 'DEVICEID'.

How the procedure will be:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_GMAPSDATA]
(
 @DEVICENUMBER varchar(50)
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @DEVICEID INT

SET @DEVICEID=(SELECT DEVICEID FROM DEVICEMASTER WHERE DEVICENO= @DEVICENUMBER)
SELECT TM.REGISTRATIONNUMBER ,
    TM.CURRENTLOCATION, 
    TM.CURRENTLATLNG,
    RM.CityName AS FromCity,
    RM1.CityName AS ToCity,
    TD.DISTANCE

    FROM TRUCKMASTER TM 
    JOIN TRIPDETAIL TD ON TM.DEVICEID=TD.DEVICEID 
    JOIN REGIONMASTER RM ON RM.REGIONID =TD.FROMCTYID
    JOIN REGIONMASTER RM1 ON RM1.REGIONID=TD.TOCTYID

    WHERE DEVICEID IN (SELECT DEVICEID FROM DEVICEMASTER WHERE DEVICENO= @DEVICENUMBER)

END

GO
```

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: You are not using assigned variable @deviceid in the select query and u haven't specified the alias name in the where clause

Answer (score 2):

I expect your error message is coming from `WHERE DEVICEID IN ...` in which you don't have an alias to the column. The query doesn't know if you mean `TM.DEVICEID` or `TD.DEVICEID`, so if you change the last line to the line below, it should be fine:

```
WHERE TM.DEVICEID IN (SELECT DEVICEID FROM DEVICEMASTER WHERE DEVICENO = @DEVICENUMBER)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have formatted your query as below. Alias Name included in `Where` Clause. Always make sure to use the variables you defined in the query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_GMAPSDATA]
(
@DEVICENUMBER varchar(50)
)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DECLARE @DEVICEID INT

SET @DEVICEID=(SELECT DEVICEID FROM DEVICEMASTER WHERE DEVICENO= @DEVICENUMBER)

SELECT TM.REGISTRATIONNUMBER ,
      TM.CURRENTLOCATION, 
     TM.CURRENTLATLNG,
      RM.CityName AS FromCity,
      RM1.CityName AS ToCity,
     TD.DISTANCE
FROM TRUCKMASTER TM 
INNER JOIN TRIPDETAIL TD 
   ON TM.DEVICEID  = TD.DEVICEID 
INNER JOIN REGIONMASTER RM 
   ON RM.REGIONID  = TD.FROMCTYID
INNER JOIN REGIONMASTER RM1 
   ON RM1.REGIONID = TD.TOCTYID
WHERE TM.DEVICEID   = @DEVICEID;

SET NOCOUNT OFF; 

END
```

Comment: aliases. awww yisss! (Y)